# Dojo ValidatedTextBox Not Working

Tags: dojo

I have searched high and low for solution for this but I have not been able to find anything.  I am playing around with the dojo ValidatationTextBox dijit.  I have tried to both declarative and programmatic methods and every time it comes up as a readonly input field.  The code provided shows my attempt using the declarative method.  I got the exact same result using a programmatic route similar to the "new textbox" calls below.  In both methods the html for the ValidatationTextBox is generated with two child divs.  One with class=dijitReset dijitValidationContainer and one with class=dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer.  It is the later class that holds all of the html input and dijit properties and the former that defines the form as readonly and also gives it a value of 'x'.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help or explanation regarding why this is not working will be much appreciated.  Thanks

```
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox","dojo/domReady!","dojox/validate","dojox/validate/web"],
        function(parser, textbox, ValidationTextBox,validate){

            parser.parse();

            new textbox({
                    id: "fName",
                    maxlength: 25,
                    name: "fName",
                    trim: "true",
                    propercase: "true"
            }, "fName");

            new textbox({
                    id: "lName",
                    maxlength: 25,
                    name: "lName",
                    trim: "true",
                    propercase: "true"
            }, "lName");


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="tundra">
        <h3>Sign-up for our great offers:</h3>
        <form id="registration_form">
            <div class="grouping">
                <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
                <input id="fName" /><br />
                <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
                <input id="lName" /><br />
                <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" required="true" readonly="false"
                data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                data-dojo-props="regExp:'[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}', invalidMessage:'Please enter a valid e-mail address'" /><br />
                <button id="btn">Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: From what you say, I think your CSS is not loaded properly. Also, You are calling "parser.parse();" before ensuring that the page is loaded. call parser.parse() inside the ready function.

Comment: Would be nice to see all the HTML.  Would start by changing <input tag for fName and lName to <div id="fName'></div> and <div id="lName></div>. Also, add "dojo/domReady!" to require([])

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with your regExp however you can write a keyup function and call it when the user types it will validate the email address using Dojo's built in email validation. Also for your fname and lname fields try setting `required = "true"`. You can do this to implement on the fly validation since if your fields are not required you need to call validation on your form when you post. You can refer to this [Form Validation Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/HGBnq/)

**HTML**

```
 <input type= "text" name ="email" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" missingMessage="Email Address Required" invalidMessage="Invalid Email Address" onkeyup="validateMe(this.value);" required="true" />
```

**js**

```
function validateMe(email){    
  var isValid = false;    
  isValid = dojox.validate.isEmailAddress(email);
  return isValid;    
}
```